# Plugin Folder and no Access to wp-content

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, plugins, file-manager, bluehost

I had the plugin WP File Manager in the wordpress plugin area, so I searched for a solution in order to solve another problem. I found one solution and it was to change the name of the folder plugin and then change it again, when I changed I lost all my plugins. I do not have an issue redownloading my plugins BUT now because I mistakenly deleted the whole [Plugins] folder instead of just the one plugin, when I try to install any plugins now I get the error message ‘Installation failed: Could not create directory.’

So I have clearly deleted a directory and I know I should go to the original cpanel or file system to fix it, the problem is I don’t have access to that. Is there any chance I can fix it?

And I don't know where exactly is located my website, I have a domain and hosting files in Bluehost and also have an Instance in AWS and Lightsail and Bitnami is also involved in wordpress I can see the directory path starting with opt/bitnami/wordpress.

I have try everything to log into the server, key files, ssh access terminal coding, everything and nothing helps.

Comment: Figure out who the host is (enter the domain on this page to get some info that might help you determine that for sure:  https://intodns.com/)  Then, gain access to your hosting account so you can fix this.  You won't be able to add the plugins folder back via the WordPress Dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like by deleting the plugin's folder you got into trouble and you may also have file permission and ownership issues inside the WordPress directory. So you got the error like "Installation failed: Could not create directory."

If you are using AWS LightSail, there are different options to connect to SSH

- Go to AWS LightSail - server's instances and connect through the
  terminal.
- You can check your current position by typing the command: `ls`
- Now go to the WordPress directory
  (New Instances: stack/wordpress/wp-content)
  (Old Instances: apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content)
- Type a command to make a plugins folder: `mkdir plugins`
- Check the file permission and ownership of a folder: `ls -la plugins`
  It should have file permission as "drwxrwxr-x" which means 775
  And ownership should be "bitnami & daemon".
- You must change as `sudo chmod 775 plugins` and `sudo chown bitnami:daemon plugins`
- If there is a missing index.php file inside the plugins folder then create it and write the missing code also. Also for index.php give the file permission as 664 and ownership to "bitnami & daemon".

In this way, you can re-create the plugins folder manually from the terminal but you can also use FileZilla where you can use an SSH key to connect, you will get a clear file directory and you can view/change the file permission but for ownership use terminal.

Check the wp-content directory folder's file permission and ownership also. Understand the server and WordPress file structure and their file permission.

Comment: Hi Roshan, I did all of that at the end, and I lost the wordpress access, I lost all the website now. Can you please let me know what I can do? Thank you.

Comment: It is giving me This page isn’t working woori.ca redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Hi @andrea-peñaherrera, there is no such command line that makes a 503 error, check your server, service, and database status, if it is not running then restart it. Also, stop the server and reactivate/reboot it. Make sure you enter the correct command line and spelling.

Comment: Hi Roshan Khapung at the end it worked, I am able to enter to the SSH and FTP and wordpress dashboard, but it created another wordpress IP address, now I want to connect to the domain name that I used to have but no idea how to do it. If know anything that can help me, please let me know.

Comment: You need to make your website IP stable to not change frequently, go to the AWS Lightsail server's network tab, and you have the option to make a static IP. check the tutorial - https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/lightsail-create-static-ip

Comment: Thank you, then you know how I can connect with the original domain? Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it.